# How can I return multiple columns in a column subquery in Access 2003 JET SQL?

Tags: sql, select, inner-join, ms-access-2003, jet

I'm working on a project which records performance metrics of employees on a daily basis.

The `records` table holds one row per day of the employees productivity; each column holds a count of items completed in that category, plus total shift time and the date as a Short Date.

The `metrics` table holds an effective date (Short Date) and columns which match the productivity columns in the `records` table which keep track of the expected hourly rate of production.

The `employees` table simply contains employee names and phone extensions.

The Employee Report can be set to variable date ranges to show performance over time, and the `GroupLevel(1).GroupOn` is set via VBA as well (creates sections by week, month, quarter, etc).

The goal here is to create a query which returns all rows of the records table (which will later be filtered based on the `whereCondition` passed when opening the report) along with the row of the `metrics` table which is the highest date less than or equal to the `records.date`. So far, I've only been able to get the ID (or any other single field) of the `metrics` row:

```sql
SELECT records.*, employees.first, employees.last, employees.ext,  
   (
    SELECT TOP 1 metrics.id 
    FROM metrics 
    WHERE metrics.date<=records.date 
    ORDER BY metrics.date DESC
   ) AS MetricsID
FROM employees 
INNER JOIN records ON employees.id = records.employee
ORDER BY employees.last;
```

What I am looking for is a way to write this query so I have all columns in each row - when I run my calculation function during `GroupFooter2_Format` it will mean I won't have to query against `metrics` for each row in the date range.

Bonus gratitude if you can tell me how to write a query which will automatically divide the column in `records` by the corresponding one in `metrics`, so I can just populate the fields directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on these lines may suit:

```
SELECT Records.*, Metrics.*, 
    Round([Records].[Productivity]/[Metrics].[ExpectedRate],2) AS Calc, 
    Employees.First, Employees.Last
FROM ((Records 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT records.ID, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 metrics.id 
        FROM metrics 
        WHERE metrics.date<=record.date 
        ORDER BY metrics.date DESC ) AS MetricsID 
     FROM records)  AS j 
ON Records.ID = j.ID) 
INNER JOIN Metrics ON j.MetricsID = Metrics.ID) 
INNER JOIN Employees ON Records.Employee = Employees.ID;
```

However, I am a little suspicious that the data presented has been simplified in that you mention "items completed in that category" but do not mention a category id in either the records table or the metrics table.

In addition, `date` is a reserved word and therefore a terrible name for almost anything.

It is very rarely a good idea to select *, you should use the field (column) names.

Comment: This looks good, I will try it out this afternoon when I have a chance. The data isn't stored with a category type, each column is its own category. Not quite best practice but it was originally built in a hurry...going to save that fix for "2.0"

Comment: The only problem here is the parameters in the Round() function are complaining that "The specified field 'records.Productivity' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement', but I can do the calculation itself in VBA as long as I have the relevant metrics, and the query works if I remove the calculated field.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that although the query works in data sheet view, any attempt to reference named fields in a report control causes the same error as above.

Comment: @4AM The problem arises from not specifying the fields to include. If you post your own SQL, that is, modified from the above, as an edit to your original post I may be able to help.

Comment: I was able to eventually get it working. (It's difficult to post the actual SQL because there are a lot of fields and I have to log in to StackOverflow from my phone; the work firewall blocks the OpenID somehow). I added `AS r2` after `ON Records.ID = j.ID)` and the reference to `records` was no longer ambiguous; calculations are working correctly and I've eliminated about 7-8 pages of VBA code. This has really opened my eyes to the true power of joins when working with SQL.

Comment: @4AM I think I felt a little dizzy when I finally found what you could do with even quite simple SQL and VBA :)  If you are not already familiar with aliases, check them out, they really clean up the SQL: `SELECT MyReallyLongTable.Field1 FROM MyReallyLongTable` becomes `SELECT m.Field1 FROM MyReallyLongTable m`